# Chrome scrollbar visibility toggles on/off when window resized to scrollbar height

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scrollbar

When a window area is redimensioned **exactly on the same height where the scrollbar starts**, the scrollbar is shown (webkit-scrollbar) as inactive (without a scrollbar-thumb) and then typing on the field will cause a scrollbar visibility to keep toggling.

Is it a bug? How to workaround without changing the page sizing?

This strange behavior is happening on Chrome, Chromium (Windows and Ubuntu) and Edge, but not on Firefox.

[image: Inactive Scrollbar]

```css
    .container {
        height:176px;
        background-color:gray;
        color: white;
        margin:2%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        test:<input type="text" />
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share a live code?

Comment: @djangotic I recorded a video to show the behavior: https://youtu.be/QL2dbjrFTrc. It only happens when the window is exactly dimensioned to start to show the scrollbar.

Comment: thats bug,i am having no problem with your code on chrome.

Comment: @djangotic you have to use the exactly height dimension to the bug happens, It happens on different webkit browsers and also Windows or Linux. it's very unlucky to happens on any app, because it has to attend this very unlikely height condition, but it creates a very bad experience to the user, as happened to on my app. I am searching a simple straight solution without chaging the page structure or removing the margin % because I cannot make big changes on this app from this company.